# Visual Studio 2015 - Editing TypeScript files

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

For some odd reason, I cannot* edit TypeScript files in Visual Studio 2015. The really weird thing is that I can create new lines and add tabs, but nothing else.

I tried updating to the latest version of TypeScript for VS2015 to no avail.  I thought maybe it was project related so I opened a ts file without having a project loaded - same problem.  I saw some other posts indicating problems with ReSharper cache, so I tried deleting those as well as disabling Re# - no luck.

Anybody have any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm also having the same issue. It did work for some months, then abruptly failed. I've seen some other issue threads that seem related (e.g https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/44), but I haven't found a workaround.

Comment: I ended up reinstalling Windows.

Comment: Did it work? Also, are you on Win10?

Comment: It worked.  I haven't tried updating any of the TS or web stuff for fear I would end up in the same state.  Yes, Windows 10.

Comment: I have the same issue. I tried to clean the Resharper cache folder, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem but fortunately I solved it quite soon.

At some point editing stopped working for ts file in VS 2015 and I noticed that it happened after I updated tsconfig.json file. It turned out that this issue was caused by comments I left at the beginning of the file (I had commented out sample config and added actual config below it).

This looks weird but after playing with the config file all doubts were gone.