# Visual Studio 2015: Cannot edit TypeScript files, get exception 0x80020101

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015

Seemingly at random, VS2015 has developed an issue with TypeScript files. They are slow to load, do not have any coloring, and most importantly, won't respond to the keyboard. Other files (such as js files) seem to work fine.

The first time I load a .ts file after opening VS, I get a popup that reads "An exception has been encountered. This may be caused by an extension." It also directs me to the Activity Log, which contains a single error repeated about 100 times:

> **Description:** System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80020101): Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020101 at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.TypeScript.ScriptServices.ShimFactory.IJavaScriptExecutionEngine.AddScript(String name, String text, Int32 textLength) at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.TypeScript.ScriptServices.ShimFactory.ShimFactory.Factory.ReinitializeEngineAndFactoryIfNeeded() at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.TypeScript.ScriptServices.ShimFactory.ShimFactory.Factory.CreateOrUpdateShim(String createShimFunction, Object host, ShimAndServicesFileVersion& shimInfo) at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.TypeScript.ScriptServices.ShimFactory.ShimFactory.CreateOrUpdateShim(String caption, String createShimFunction, Object host, ShimAndServicesFileVersion& shimInfo) at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.TypeScript.ScriptServices.Proxies.AbstractProxy`1.InvokeShimMethod[T](String methodName, Object[] arguments) at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.TypeScript.ScriptServices.Proxies.ClassifierProxy.TryAddLexicalClassifications(String lineText, Int32 lexState, Int32 offset, TypeScriptLexicalClassificationMap classificationMap, ITextSnapshot snapshot, List`1 tagSpans, Int32& newEndOfLineState) at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.TypeScript.Features.Classifier.LexicalClassificationTaggerProvider.Tagger.AddLexicalClassifications(ClassifierProxy classifier, String text, Int32 lineNum, Int32 offset, ITextSnapshot snapshot, List`1 tagSpans) at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.TypeScript.Features.Classifier.LexicalClassificationTaggerProvider.Tagger.GetClassifications(NormalizedSnapshotSpanCollection spans, List`1 result) at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.TypeScript.Features.Classifier.LexicalClassificationTaggerProvider.Tagger.GetTags(NormalizedSnapshotSpanCollection spans) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Tagging.Implementation.TagAggregator`1.d__38.MoveNext()
>
> **Source:** Editor or Editor Extension

I can't for the life of me figure out what's wrong. I've updated the version of TypeScript VS is running to the most recent one, using the installer from Microsoft. Doing a tsc -v returns version 1.8.9, though the version given in Help->About Microsoft Visual Studio is 1.8.30.0. The version my project is requesting via npm is ^1.8.10.

Again, I didn't change any of these settings before the error began occurring. I did pull some changes that a coworker had checked in; these didn't change TypeScript in any obvious way, though they may have updated the version of Typings. (We're running 1.1.0.) Notably, I am having this same issue even in unrelated projects that do not use any TypeScript, although opening a .ts file for the first time appears not to throw the exception above; I'm just unable to edit the file.

My best guess is that my VS TypeScript tooling has gotten screwed up somehow, though I have no idea how that would have happened. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

**Edit:** I'm running VS2015 Professional, Update 2. The TypeScriptToolsVersion set in my .csproj is 1.8.

**Edit 2:** This was suggested as a possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2015 - Editing TypeScript files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35807201/visual-studio-2015-editing-typescript-files) which does appear similar; however the only suggested remedy in that post (removing comments from .tsconfig.json) doesn't apply to my case, as my .tsconfig is already comment-free. As well, I'd like to keep my post up as it contains much more detail than the possible duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2015 - Editing TypeScript files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35807201/visual-studio-2015-editing-typescript-files)

Comment: I've investigated the only solution suggested in that question, which is to remove comments from .tsconfig.json. Unfortunately, my .tsconfig already had no comments in it, so I have to assume the cause is something else.

Comment: Which version of WIndows are you running, and can you send both the tsconfig.json and activitylog to the address in my profile?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7. I'll send those files momentarily, thanks!

Comment: I'll remove my close vote, but it might be better to add this as an issue on [the TypeScript GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues) and discuss there, but I'll defer to @PaulvanBrenk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As best I can tell, this ended up being a bug in Visual Studio, as evinced by the many other people suffering from it.[1](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7204) To make a *very* long story short, what seems to have solved it for me was installing Visual Studio Update 3 RC.[2](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/visual-studio-prerelease-downloads)

I will note that the initial install failed, requiring a restart and breaking VS, but the Repair I did to get VS running again installed Update 3 RC correctly and the original bug was solved.